# How to start jQuery Parallax at specific location?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, parallax

I found this great example of horizontal parallax 
http://www.perandersen.no/sandbox/parallax/
The only modification I would like to make to it is make it start from far right rather then left side off the screen but I cannot work if out how to do that

Here is Jquery function used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var snowboarderPos;
    var balloonPos;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#beginningLink").click(function() {
            $.scrollTo(0,0, {duration: 2000});
        });
        $("#avalancheLink").click(function() {
            $.scrollTo(2000,0, {duration: 2000});
        });
        $("#elevatorLink").click(function() {
            $.scrollTo(4400,0, {duration: 2000});
        });
        $("#wolfLink").click(function() {
            $.scrollTo(7000,0, {duration: 2000});
        });
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
        snowboarderPos = $("#snowboarder").offset();
        balloonPos = $("#ballong").offset();
        window.onscroll = scroll;
        hideScreen();

    });

    function hideScreen() {
        $("#loadingWrap").fadeOut("slow");
        //$('html,body').animate({scrollLeft: $("#info2").offset().top},'slow');

        $("#snowboarder").animate({"top": "-=200px"}, "slow");
        $("#info1").delay(500).animate({"left": "-=200px", "width" : "350px", "fontSize" : "24px"}, "slow");
    }

    function scroll()
    {
        var xPos = window.pageXOffset;
        var element = $("#wrapper");
        var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.1);
        element.css( "left", newXPos );

        element = $("#snowboarder");
        var position = element.position();
        var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.5) + snowboarderPos.left;
        element.css( "left", newXPos );

        element = $("#elevator");
        var position = element.position();
        var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.9) + 2800;
        element.css( "left", newXPos );

        var element = $("#ballong");
        var position = element.position();
        var newXPos = Math.abs(xPos /1.2) + balloonPos.left;
        element.css( "left", newXPos );

        // $("#xpos").text(window.pageXOffset);
    }
</script>
```

does anyone know how I could achieve that?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the very last item has an `id` of `end`, just jump there via appending hash with end to the URL.

Example:
[**http://www.perandersen.no/sandbox/parallax/#end**](http://www.perandersen.no/sandbox/parallax/#end)

That said, you can have it jump there on page load using the already required `.scrollTo` plugin during window onload.

**Example:**

```
$.scrollTo('#end');
```

I made this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AY3Ej/1/) that contains the authors website with the *single addition* of the above `.scrollTo()` that answers your question.